# How to check if a members role is higher or equal to the message authors role discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So im making a ban command this is the code the first 3 if statements work fine but when it comes to checking the members role and then actually banning them it wont work.

```
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, *, reason=None):
    channel = ctx.channel
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Ban", description=f"Ban a member from the discord.", colour=discord.Colour.purple())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return

    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members == False:
        embed4=discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.purple(), 
        timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), title="Missing Permissions!", description="You don't have the required permissions to use this command!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed4)
        return

    if reason == None:
        reason = "being a jerk!"
        print("b")

    if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
        print("a")   
        embed3=discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.purple(), 
        title="Role", description="This user is a higher or the same role as you.")
        await channel.send(embed=embed3)
        return

    else:

        await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Ban", description=f" {member.mention} was banned by {ctx.author.mention}.", 
        colour=discord.Colour.purple())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
        await member.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason: You are getting a [discord.User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User) object instead of a [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member).
The first one doesn't have a "top_role" attribute, since it just refers to the user itself, what you really want is the latter, since it refers to the user as a member of the server and has the attribute you're looking for. You can take a look at the documentation for each one.

Fix:
Just change the definition to be `discord.Member`.

Correct Code:

```py
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.Member=None, *, reason=None):
    channel = ctx.channel
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Ban", description=f"Ban a member from the discord.", colour=discord.Colour.purple())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return

    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members == False:
        embed4=discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.purple(), 
        timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), title="Missing Permissions!", description="You don't have the required permissions to use this command!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed4)
        return

    if reason == None:
        reason = "being a jerk!"
        print("b")

    if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
        print("a")   
        embed3=discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.purple(), 
        title="Role", description="This user is a higher or the same role as you.")
        await channel.send(embed=embed3)
        return

    else:

        await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Ban", description=f" {member.mention} was banned by {ctx.author.mention}.", 
        colour=discord.Colour.purple())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
        await member.send(message)
```